# Como limitar um valor inserido/modificado pelo endereço de memória?

Tags: c++, memória

Como limitar um valor que foi inserido/alterado pelo endereço de memória?

PS: Eu não posso limitar pela função, essa função é apenas uma função de exemplo mostrando o problema, vou precisar passar esse objeto para funções de outras bibliotecas na qual eu não posso alterar.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename type>
class Var
{
private:
    type Value               = (type)0;
    type ClampMin            = (type)0;
    type ClampMax            = (type)0;
    bool NeedClamp           = false;
public:
    Var()                                    { }
    Var(type initialVal) : Value(initialVal) { }
    Var(type initialVal, type Min, type Max)
    {
        this->NeedClamp = true;
        this->ClampMin = Min; this->ClampMax = Max;

        this->operator=(initialVal);
    }

    constexpr bool IsClampActive() const
    {
        return this->NeedClamp;
    }

    constexpr type Min() const
    {
        return this->ClampMin;
    }

    constexpr type Max() const
    {
        return this->ClampMax;
    }

    // Operador seguro pois consegue limitar os valores inseridos
    type& operator=(type val) noexcept
    {
        if (this->NeedClamp)
        {
            if (val > this->ClampMax)
                this->Value = this->ClampMax;
            else if (val < this->ClampMin)
                this->Value = this->ClampMin;
            else
                this->Value = val;
        }
        else
        {
            this->Value = val;
        }
        return this->Value;
    }

    // Para converter automaticamente o tipo
    // Não seguro
    // Como limitar o valor inserido nesse operador?
    operator type*()
    {
        return &this->Value;
    }

    // Para converter automaticamente o tipo
    // Não seguro
    // Como limitar o valor inserido nesse operador?
    operator type&()
    {
        return this->Value;
    }

    template <typename typeVal>
    constexpr bool operator==(typeVal val) const
    {
        return (this->Value == (type)val);
    }

    template <typename typeVal>
    constexpr bool operator!=(typeVal val) const
    {
        return (this->Value != (type)val);
    }
};

#define MIN_VALORTESTE                    1.f
#define MAX_VALORTESTE                    100.f

float problema(float& valor)
{
    valor = 200.f; // Vai alterar o valor para um valor maior que o limite definido(100.f), como limitar o valor inserido nesse caso?
    return valor;
}

int main()
{
    //Var<float> Valor_Teste = 50.f;
    Var<float> Valor_Teste = { /* Valor inicial da variável */ 50.f, /* Valor minimo permitido para a variável*/ MIN_VALORTESTE, /* Valor maximo permitido para a variável */ MAX_VALORTESTE };

    std::cout << problema(Valor_Teste) << std::endl;

    // Mostrando o novo valor da variável(vai mostrar um valor inválido, pois está maior que o limite definido(MAX_VALORTESTE))
    std::cout << Valor_Teste << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Na linha que você comenta  "Não seguro" (...) está praticamente jogando fora a classe que limita o valor.... O comentário está correto, o que faz parecer que você já sabe onde está o problema...

Comment: Sim, eu sei onde está o problema, mas eu preciso da sobrecarga desse operador por conta da dependência das outras bibliotecas do projeto

Answer (score 0):

O tipo `float` não possui a opção embutida de limitação do valor. Se você precisa limitar os valores, precisa fazê-lo enquanto o tipo ainda é interpretado como essa classe que você criou, e depois convertê-lo para o tipo requerido pela biblioteca externa. Inclusive, aconselho que você declare uma função explícita para isso, do tipo:

```
template <typename type>
//(...)
type* converter_para_type_pt{
    return &this->Value;
}
//(...)
```

E chame essa função quando precisar passar para biblioteca externa, e não contar com operador implícito, pois este pode ser inferido pelo compilador em muitas situações...

Para 'automaticamente' limitar o valor, você **tem** que usar a classe definida:

```
template <typename T>
T problema(Var<T>& valor)
//aqui desenvolve a função usando os métodos de Var<T>
```

Comment: Isso não resolve os meus problemas, pois eu ia ter que modificar todas as funções das outras bibliotecas que meu projeto usa(e são muitas),
o que eu quero dizer é que o tipo da variável que vai ser passado para cada função de outras bibliotecas do meu projeto obrigatoriamente tem que ser int, float, double, etc, não posso simplesmente modificar cada função(milhares de funções) de um projeto enorme.

Comment: Se você quer uma classe que limita o valor, essa classe é uma, se você quer um double, é outra coisa. Não tem como mudar o comportamento dos doubles (ou floats etc). Eu entendi o seu problema, estou dizendo que a limitação de valor tem de ocorrer *antes* de passar como double.